# How do I find data against a date for an item from another work sheet

Tags: date, indexing, match

How do I find data against a date for an item from another work sheet. I am unable to use vlookup or Hlookup as that Item number has multiple number of data for different week date. For eg on the first sheet I have item ABC and I want data for that same item against date 01/13/2014 and 01/20/2014 from another sheet. How do I Pull exact cell data for that item.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got this working.

=INDEX(Sheet2!A$1:H$9,MATCH(A2,Sheet2!A$1:A$9,0),MATCH(B2,Sheet2!A$1:H$1,0))

The idea is to match the index by matching the intersection of your item number in row and your week date in column in sheet2. You would get #N/A as well but ignore those.

Hope this helps. Enjoy!!!